# Issue copying an excel sheet with pivot table to another workbook with EPPLUS

Tags: copy, pivot-table, epplus, worksheet

Am using below code to copy an excel sheet with pivot table to another workbook but am getting this error when the excution reachs the copy code line item : "Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in EPPlus.dll - Internal error: Pivot table uri does not exist in package. "

---

ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial

```
        Dim strFileExtension As String = "xlsx"

        Dim strRatingsTemplateFile As String = Strings.Trim(SQLGetDataFromTable_dataTable(SqlConn, "tbl_Syst_ConfigurationSystem").Rows(0)("DocumentsUncPath").ToString()) + "\" + "templates" + "\" + GetLocalResourceObject("strXlsxFileName.Text") + "." + strFileExtension

        Dim excelTemplate = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(strRatingsTemplateFile))

        Dim excel As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage()

  excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(excelTemplate.Workbook.Worksheets(4).Name, excelTemplate.Workbook.Worksheets(4))

  ' The excelTemplate.Workbook.Worksheets(4) excel sheet has a pivot table 

        If strFileExtension = "xlsm" Then 
            excel.Workbook.CreateVBAProject()
        End If

        Using memoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            If strFileExtension = "xlsx" Then
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            Else
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"
            End If
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + GetLocalResourceObject("strXlsxFileName.Text") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("hhmmss") + "." + strFileExtension)             
            excel.SaveAs(memoryStream)
            memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.[End]()
        End Using
```